# Trying to make my VBA run a little bit faster

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, return-value, with-statement

I am New to VBA, so my codes are usually very slow/suboptimized.

In one of my programs I have cells in the sheet that has to be filled when the user press a button, the renges change depending on the button but the concept is the same.

So I did this monstrosity:

```
Cells((Range("namedrange").Row + 5), 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells(4, 7).Value
Cells((Range("namedrange").Row + 5), 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells(4, 8).Value
Cells((Range("namedrange").Row + 5), 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells(4, 9).Value
Cells((Range("namedrange").Row + 5), 8).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells(4, 10).Value
Cells((Range("namedrange").Row + 5) + 1, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells(5, 7).Value
Cells((Range("namedrange").Row + 5) + 1, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells(5, 8).Value
Cells((Range("namedrange").Row + 5) + 1, 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells(5, 9).Value
Cells((Range("namedrange").Row + 5) + 1, 8).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells(5, 10).Value
```

but later changed to:

```
    With Range("namedrange")
        .Offset(5).Columns(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(4, 7).Value
        .Offset(5).Columns(3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(4, 8).Value
        .Offset(5).Columns(5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(4, 9).Value
        .Offset(5).Columns(8).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(4, 10).Value
        .Offset(6).Columns(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(5, 7).Value
        .Offset(6).Columns(3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(5, 8).Value
        .Offset(6).Columns(5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(5, 9).Value
        .Offset(6).Columns(8).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(5, 10).Value
    End With
```

which is a bit faster, however I feel that it is still suboptimized. And I would like to know if there is a way to make it cleaner/more elegant.
Just to be noted that there are discontinuities in the columns, e.g. it starts in the 1st columns but jumps to the 3rd and then to the 5th and at last to the 8th.

The code works but it is slow, I just want a way to make it faster/cleaner.

Comment: A common way that you can stop screen refrash for higher speed.
And is this operation to be repeated in loop for many times?

Comment: If `ThisWorlbook.Sheets(3)` exists at compile-time then you can use its CodeName instead of pulling it from the `Sheets` collection over an over again. `Sheet3.Cells(...)`

Comment: Also watch out for implicit ActiveSheet and ActiveWorkbook references, they're a common source of bugs. [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) can help with that.

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't understand a lot about this comment thread... but I will research about them and try to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

### Using Variables

- In regards to efficiency, that's about it: you're using the most efficient way to copy values from one cell to another aka *copying by assignment*.
- If you want it to be more flexible, maintainable, and readable(?), here are some ideas.
- Additionally, you can move the remaining magic numbers and text to constants at the beginning of the code or even use the constants as arguments.

```vb
Sub CopyValues()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Specify the worksheet if you know it.
    'Dim dnrg As Range: Set dnrg = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("NamedRange")
    ' Otherwise, make sure the workbook is active.
    If Not wb Is ActiveWorkbook Then wb.Activate
    Dim dnrg As Range: Set dnrg = Range("NamedRange")
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dnrg.Range("A1,C1,E1,H1").Offset(5)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = drg.Cells.Count
    
    ' If you know the tab name, use it instead of the index (3).
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(3)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("G4").Resize(, cCount)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
        
    For r = 0 To 1
        For c = 1 To cCount
            drg.Offset(r).Cells(c).Value = srg.Offset(r).Cells(c).Value
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: I see, this code looks very good and thanks a lot for your answer, but one problem I see for my case is the usage of the ´´´dnrg.Range("A1,C1,E1,H1")´´´ part because the sheet keeps getting updated and the values of those cells also modify, that is the reason why I am using named ranges and the offsets. Can I change this specific part of the code for something that constant? Like you did ´´´dnrg.Range("A1,C1,E1,H1")´´´, but istead of the A1, C1, etc, I would put the named range as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing Excel for values from VBA is a slow operation and this adds up when you make multiple requests. When you are essentially retrieving the same information on a repetitive basis there are two two methods can be used to reduce access times.

1. Replace a lookup with a calculated value
2. Use a with statement

Thus you code could be written as

```
Dim myCol as long 
myCol =Range("namedrange").Row + 5

With ThisWorkook.Sheets(5)
    Cells(myCol, 1).Value = .Cells(4, 7).Value
    Cells(myCol, 3).Value = .Cells(4, 8).Value
    Cells(myCol, 5).Value = .Cells(4, 9).Value
    Cells(myCol, 8).Value = .Cells(4, 10).Value
    myCol=myCol+1 ' trivial example
    Cells(mycol, 1).Value = .Cells(5, 7).Value
    Cells(myCol, 3).Value = .Cells(5, 8).Value
    Cells(myCol, 5).Value = .Cells(5, 9).Value
    Cells(myCol, 8).Value = .Cells(5, 10).Value
End with
```

Please also install the free, opensource, and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.  The code inspections will help you write VBA that is much more correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable screenupdating during execution.

**Disable ScreenUpdating**

1. To disable ScreenUpdating, at the beginning of your code put this line:

   `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

**Enable ScreenUpdating**

2. To re-enable ScreenUpdating, at the end of your code put this line:

   `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what would happen if you use **all** the .Offset parameters, row and column. Example:

```
With Range("namedrange")
    .Offset(5, 0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(4, 7).Value
    .Offset(5, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(4, 8).Value
    .Offset(5, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(4, 9).Value
    .Offset(5, 7).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(4, 10).Value
    .Offset(6, 0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(5, 7).Value
    .Offset(6, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(5, 8).Value
    .Offset(6, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(5, 9).Value
    .Offset(6, 7).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(5, 10).Value
End With
```